# Display the day in japanese language

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using the following date() to display the day.

```
date('l', $timestamp)
```

I would like to use it in japanese.

I tried the following: But it still displays in english.

```
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "ja_JP.utf8");
 $date_format = "%A";
 $date_string = strftime($date_format);
 echo $date_string;
```

Any help would be appreciatd.

Comment: Did you try this ? :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/49862373/4925008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define the variable that a japanese day name is set because PHP can't return it directly.
`date('w')` returns numeric representation of the day, so please try following code.

```
$days = array('日', '月', '火', '水', '木', '金', '土');
echo $days[date('w')] . '曜日';
```